# Sending POST variables to a browser window from AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm building an AIR application. Basically, what I'm looking to do is using navigateToUrl() to open a browser window, assign it a "name" and then, send variables to that newly opened window using the POST method.

**EDIT : I need the window to be visible, this is why I absolutely need to use the navigateToUrl() function**

I already know that I CAN'T DO something like this, that the AIR application will send the variables using the GET method...

```
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.myVar = "Hello my friend";

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com/my-page.php");
req.method = "POST":
req.data = vars;

navigateToURL(req);
```

Considering the amount of variables I have to send (multiline texts) I absolutely need to send my variables using the POST method else Internet Explorer is truncating the query string... Works fine in Firefox and Safari but unfortunately, we will always have (hope not!) to deal with IE..

So I was thinking something like this :

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

private var _timer:Timer;

protected function loadPage():void
{
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com/my-page.php");
    navigateToURL(req, "myPageName");

    _timer = new Timer(3000, 1);
    _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, postVars);
    _timer.start();
}

protected function postVars(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    // I'm looking to send variables using the POST method to "myPageName"
    // and possibly using URLVariables()??

    _timer.stop();
}
```

Any idea Flex coders? THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're going to need to do is open up a page you have control over, then use `ExternalInterface` to inject the values into a hidden form and then execute the post operation in that page `form.submit()`, etc.

This can happen almost instantly and it will all appear very seamless to the end user.

Comment: Bingo!! I'm on the good way, communicating with JS in my mx:HTML window.... Will pass those variables on Monday. Thanks and have a great week-end!